# Find conversation between one or more users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with finding conversations between given user_ids.

SQL table:

```
+-------------------+
| conversation_user |
+-------------------+
| conversation_id   |
| user_id           |
+-------------------+
```

I've tried

```
SELECT `conversation_id` FROM `conversation_user` WHERE `user_id` IN (X, Y) HAVING COUNT(*) = N
```

But it does not work correctly. Any idea how to select the correct conversation_id? A conversation can be between one or more users.

Edit:

```
+-----------------+---------+
| conversation_id | user_id |
+-----------------+---------+
|               1 |       1 | 
|               1 |       2 | 
+-----------------+---------+
|               2 |       1 | 
|               2 |       3 | 
+-----------------+---------+
|               3 |       1 | 
+-----------------+---------+
|               4 |       1 | 
|               4 |       2 | 
|               4 |       3 | 
+-----------------+---------+
```

Let's say I want to get the conversation between user 1 and 2. The result must be 1, not 1 and 4 or 4.

Comment: What @Tomtom said or maybe having count(conversation_id) > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED!** I resolved problem with this query.

```
SELECT cu.`conversation_id` 
FROM `conversation_user` cu 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `conversation_id`
    FROM `conversation_user` 
    WHERE `user_id` IN (X, Y) 
    GROUP BY `conversation_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = Z 
) cu2 ON cu.conversation_id=cu2.conversation_id
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
HAVING COUNT(*) = Z;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you lack `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT `conversation_id` 
FROM `conversation_user` 
WHERE `user_id` IN (X, Y) 
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = N
```

or

```
SELECT `conversation_id` 
FROM `conversation_user` a
WHERE `user_id` IN (X, Y) 
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid)
        FROM `conversation_user` b
        WHERE b.`conversation_id` = a.`conversation_id`
        GROUP BY b.`conversation_id`
    )
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61828/1)

Comment: These queries does not return one value, it also includes where these users and someone else are involved

Comment: @Kaspar it will generate the result you want, check the fiddle above. The fiddle contains 4 conversation_id but on the ID=2 will be returned.

Comment: As you can see in my example, it fails when one user has conversation with himself. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e17f/2/0 I already posted working solution too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT `conversation_id`,count(*) Number_of_conversations FROM `conversation_user` 
    WHERE `user_id` IN (X, Y) and 
   `user_id` not in(select `user_id` from `conversation_user` where `user_id` not in(X, Y))
    GROUP BY `conversation_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: This query also includes all conversations where these users are included. I want only these result where ONLY given users and not somebody else are involved.

Comment: I replaced X with 1 and Y with 2 and still got 1 and 4 for result (2 rows). Please see my example data above.